# Iterating for loop only once for same values

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, set

I have this:

```
names = {"Micky": "Mouse", "Goofy": "Black", "Pit": "Black", "Donald": "Trump"}
```

and I want to iterate through this dictionary with a for loop but only once for `"Black"`.
Something like the following:

```
for value in names.iter_only_once_values():
    print value

Output: "Mouse" , "Black" , "Trump"
```

Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
for value in set(names.values()):
    print value
```

Using a set will remove any duplicates. The output for above is:

```
Mouse
Black
Trump
```

Alternatively, you can use `unique_everseen` recipe from https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html like this:

```
for value in unique_everseen(names.itervalues()):
     print value
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
for key in {k: v for v, k in names.iteritems()}:
    print(key)
```

This will reverse you dictionary setting, values as keys, and keys as values. So you will get the desired output:

```
Mouse
Black
Trump
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this:

```python
for name in dict.fromkeys(names.values()).keys():
    print name
```

Output:

```python
Mouse
Black
Trump
```

This approach can be useful when you need use `OrderedDict` instead of `dict`, for example:

```python
from collections import OrderedDict

# dictionary names is sorted by values
ordered_names = OrderedDict(sorted(names.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))
# dictionary names is printed in desired order
for name in OrderedDict.fromkeys(ordered_names.values()).keys():
    print name
```

Output:

```python
Black
Mouse
Trump
```